# Buscar por id Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express.js

Olá pessoal estou seguindo o livro *Getting Mean* mas me deparei com um problema na qual não consigo resolver. Tenho um documento que mostro abaixo pegando dados do Mongo, e nele tenho subdocumentos no caso *reviews* na qual quero pegar pelo id.
**Meu problema é que não consigo retornar o subdocumento pelo id. Ele retorna sempre vazio. Preciso de ajuda!**

```
module.exports.reviewsReadOne = function (req, res) {
  Loc
    .findById(req.params.locationid)
    .select('name reviews')
    .exec(
    function(err, location) {
      sendJsonResponse(res, 200,location);
    });
};
```

Aqui irá me mostrar todo resultado da consulta que é este:

```
{
"_id": "59c0115558d09042f1bd203e",
"name": "Starcups",
"reviews": [
    {
        "author": "Simon Holmes",
        "id": "59c0135658d09042f1bd203f",
        "rating": 5,
        "timestamp": "2013-07-16T03:00:00.000Z",
        "reviewText": "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about this",
        "createdOn": "2017-09-22T13:44:22.380Z"
    }
]
```

}

Eu quero acessar o subdocumento reviews pelo id. Então fiz:

```
module.exports.reviewsReadOne = function (req, res) {
  Loc
    .findById(req.params.locationid)
    .select('name reviews')
    .exec(
    function(err, location) {
      var review;
      review = location.reviews.id('59c0135658d09042f1bd203f');
      sendJsonResponse(res, 200,review);
    });
};
```

E recebi a resposta

```
null
```

Eu esperava receber o reviews por completo e não nulo. Não sei qual o problema aqui. Alguém tem alguma ideia aí pra resolver isso ?

Comment: _"essa resposta do meu servidor"_ - queres dizer cliente ou servidor? pois em baixo falas em servidor de novo

Comment: Meu "xará"! Acho que está faltando o index `[0]`:  `review = location.reviews[0].id(req.params.reviewid);`

Comment: Se a pergunta estiver mais clara a resposta é bem rápida. Mas eu ainda não percebi o que vem do servidor, o que vem da Base de Dados e o que vem/vai para o cliente...  Podes explicar melhor de onde vêm as partes do código que tens na pergunta?

Comment: Cara mudei a pergunta. Eu achava que o problema estava em alguma coisa com minha manipulação de javascript, então apliquei o que biio falou, deu certo pra pegar os outros valores mas o id que é um método do Mongo que pelo que entendi do livro vai fazer a consulta no subdocumento.
Dá uma lida e vê se melhorou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que procuras é:

```
var review = location.reviews.find(rev => rev.id == '59c0135658d09042f1bd203f');
// ou
var review = location.reviews.find(rev => rev.id == req.params.locationid);
```

Assim procuras nessa array `reviews` o objeto cuja propriedade `id` é igual à string que lhe passas. O `find` retorna o primeiro objeto que verificar a condição.